# Output only JSON values using NodeJS Express for an API

Tags: node.js, json, api, express

I'm creating an API using NodeJS and Express and can create my JSON response after querying my database. I want to minimize the size of the response and only output the values and not the keys. Here is the response I am creating.

```
const api = (req, res) => {
    pool.query(query, (err, response) => {
        if (err){
        }
    res.status(200).json(response.rows);
})
```

The response from the query is a simple table (I'm omitting columns to simplify).

```
Time Values
1 50
2 40
3 70
4 10
```

The actual JSON response is:

```
[{"time":1,"Values":"50"},{"time":2,"Values":"40"},{"time":3,"Values":"70"},{"time":4,"Values":"10"}]
```

My target output is:

```
[[1,50],[2,40],[3,70],[4,10]]
```

Is there a simple option to change with this line?

```
res.status(200).json(response.rows);
```

Or do I need to manipulate the response form the query to remove the column headers? I'm using Postgres and not sure how I would do that?

Comment: that output is not valid json

Comment: Thanks, that was a simplification mistake on my part. I revised the question and have valid JSON as my target output. I actually do not need it to be JSON and could use csv style with just commas separating the values and a new row for every item. I would like to know if there is a JSON solution.

Comment: Look at array map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
response.rows.map( row => {
  return [row.Time, +row.Values];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the format I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the data type of response.rows is 
It the data type of response.rows is JSON then, convert this to Object type

```
const responseRows = JSON.parse(response.rows);
```

If the data type of response.rows is object then, not need to do anything

```
const responseRows = response.rows;
```

at this point your response.rows is an object

```
const actResponse = responseRows.map(el => {
 return[ el.time, Number(el.Values) ]
});
res.status(200).json(actResponse);
```